# How to change background of Text block in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Given a QTextBlock retrieved from QPlainTextEdit, I want to change background of the text in that block. I know how to do this with the help of textCursor() but in this case textCursor could be somewhere else. I am traversing through the file text line by line and would like to change background of the current line irrespective of the cursor position. Please let me know if it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with moving the cursor to the line you want to mark?
You can save an old cursor position if you need.

```
int oldPos = edit->textCursor().position();

QTextCursor cursor = edit->textCursor();
int oldPos = cursor.position();

int linePos = // get the line position

cursor.setPosition(linePos);
cursor.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
cursor.setCharFormat(format);

cursor.setPosition(oldPos);
edit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```